# GetVolumeInformationW stuck when plugging USB in and out quickly

Tags: filesystems, wdk

I am trying to determine whether or not a filesystem is accessible before attaching to it with microsofts minispy example. To keep things short, I am provided a device name path, such as `\Device\HarddiskVolume4\`. I figured I could use FilterGetDosName to get a root path which would be consistent and then use GetVolumeInformationW to determine whether or not the volume was actually was attached;

```
BOOL result = GetVolumeInformationW(rootPath, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

My issue is, however, that if I pull my USB in and out quickly. It gets stuck here as it attempts to get the data but the volume gets disconnected. How do I safely determine whether or not a volume is attached before attaching my minifilter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called: `GetLogicalDriveStringsW` in order to get the path name of a device rather than working with a nonpersistant devicename as stated in OP. After some logic that handles each drive individually and determining differences, so that you can attach to new devices, you use the `GetVolumeInformationW(letter.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

My other errors that I got when writing this post was unrelated to this issue. Point is: use `GetLogicalDriveStringsW` and `GetVolumeInformationW`.